# Sharing Canon Inkjet IP4000

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, network-printer

Let me first start by acknowledging that this question has been asked in very similar ways previously, I am aware of them but none of them have been resolved in a way that's relevant to me or that I am able to replicate. So I thought I'd give a go at explaining my issue specifically.

I am attempting to share a Canon Inkjet IP4000 on a 32-bit Win 7 machine and access it from a 64-bit Win 7 machine.

When I try to access the printer via the network it of course says there is no driver and attempts to look for one, which fails.

I have attempted to (on the 32-bit machine) look for the 64-bit drivers but it says they are not available and that I can only add them by the "Have Disk" button.

Similarly, I have tried plugging the printer into my 64-bit machine but it does not detect it. In the end I had to force it to use a IP4500 series driver in order to print a test page. This is fine if I want the printer on my main machine, which I don't.

Putting it back on the 32-bit machine returns it to its elusive state.

In an ideal world I could download the 64-bit INF, chuck it on the 32-bit machine and make it go "here look, this is the driver, now we're cool" alas thanks to the fact that the "Add-on" driver (which makes no sense considering I HAVE NO DRIVER IN THE FIRST PLACE) executes differently depending on whether its run on 32-bit or 64-bit.

If I've missed a trick please let me know, if I've done something wrong so far please let me know, in fact if you know anything at all on this and could help in any way, for the love of all that is good, let me know. This is driving me insane.

Thank you very much in advance,

Wolf

Answer (score 0):

Just download the correct 64 bit driver installer from Canon and install it on your 64 bit machine.  Then when you add the shared printer, it should see that the driver is already installed and won't need to look on the 32 bit machine for it.

Comment: There is no 64-bit Canon driver to download. There is a driver add-on but it expects you to have the driver already. There is no plug and play functionality like I expected. I had to manually look through window's collection of drivers and had to find an approximation. As far as I can tell there is no IP4000 driver.

Comment: Hmm, looks like Canon has an actual driver for XP x64, maybe that would work?

Comment: Could you link me to it? I've never actually been able to find anything other than utilities and the add-on driver.

Comment: Choose XP(X64) and it lists an actual driver.  http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_ip_series/pixma_ip4000#DriversAndSoftware

Comment: Thats XP, I have stated that I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, and it's possible that it may work in Windows 7.